# How to remove items in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble with my react to do list I have created. Every entry is being automatically removed on submit and it only started when I added in a remove function.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import './Items.scss';

export default class Items extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todoItem: []
        }
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
    }


    addItem(item) {
        this.setState({
            todoItem: [...this.state.todoItem, item]
        });
    }
    remove(id) {
        this.setState({
          todoItem: this.state.todoItem.filter(t => t.id !== id)
        });
      }
    render() {
        const todos = this.state.todoItem.map(todo => {
            return <TodoItem todo={todo.todo} key={todo.id} id={todo.id} removeTodo={this.remove}/>
        });

        return (
            <>
            <div className="items">
                {todos}
            </div>            
            <TodoForm addItem={this.addItem}/>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the code sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/young-sunset-lujxk?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a `.bind` in your `TodoItem` class. You have:

```js
this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove(this);
```

but it should be:

```js
this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
```

as a result you are invoking the remove handler in the constructor instead of binding it to the class object.

Comment: If you are using `Create React App` you can use the experimental [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) instead of binding methods. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) is an example.